# How are "Vati" and "Mutti" used?

Tags: meaning, colloquial

I am confused on how *Vati* and *Mutti* are used. As I understand it, *Vater* is used like *father* in English while *Mutter* is like *mother.* So would *Vati* and *Mutti* be more of a colloquial thing like *mum* or *dad?*

Comment: Maybe the better question is [*where*](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Anrede_Mutter.jpg) they are used.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, „Vati“ and „Mutti“ are two of many different pet names for „Vater“ and „Mutter“. Here is an [example](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-1/f02a-b/) of how many names there are for „Großvater“ and „Großmutter“.

As you can see  „Opi“ and „Omi“ are very rarely used. The same applies to „Vati“ and „Mutti“ (See [Ngramm](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Mama%2CPapa%2CMutti%2CVati&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CMama%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CPapa%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CMutti%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CVati%3B%2Cc0)).

The most common names for „Vater“ and „Mutter“ are just „Papa“ and „Mama“. But it’s just a matter of taste and every family handles it differently.

There are even some kids who call their parents “Mom” and “Dad” But that is displeasing to most parents. Also note that „Mutti“ can be used when you mean the Federal Chancellor of Germany „Angela Merkel“.

Comment: Thank you :) Another question, is Angela Merkel called "Mutti" as a joke or is it an actual way to refer to her? And if the Chancellor was a man, would he be known as "Vati" or would it always be known as "Mutti"?

Comment: That's a joke which boils down to the point a *Mutti* is called that way when the kids don't want to hear her nagging and endless advice. The loving, caring word is always *Mama*.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s0JXhfffaNg&t=26m40s

Comment: @Janka, I am quite sure that some people use *Mutti* in the same way that others use *Mama*.

Comment: The ngram tells you something about the frequency of words *in books*.

Comment: http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Anrede_Mutter.jpg

Comment: [Achtung, Link führt zur Springer-Presse](https://www.welt.de/kultur/article120439032/Stick-with-Mutti-Babys-wuerden-Mama-waehlen.html)

Comment: It's simply wrong when you're saying Omi/Opi/Vati/Mutti is very rarely used. Maybe it depends on the generation and region but it's widely and often used in my region and generation

Comment: For once, I do not find the Atlas der Alltagssprache results to be very insightful. Why? Because everyone can have up to two grandfathers and grandmothers, and plenty of people I've met use different terms from that list depending on who they mean.

Answer (score 1):

I remember that my mother (born in Munich in 1928) told me that in Nazi Germany the use of "Mutti" and "Vati" displaced the use of the more warm-hearted "Mama" and "Papa". One may argue that this is just an individual opinion, and I do not really know why she came to this view. What I know for certain is that she addressed my grandparents by "Mutti" and "Vati". Perhaps other relatives told her that "Mama" and "Papa" have been the traditional (Bavarian) words for addressing parents. In fact, she often spent her school vacations with relatives in a provincial and ultra catholic region of Bavaria where Hitler (believe it or not) was regarded as the *Antichrist*. She told me that she (living in the "Capital of the [National Socialist] Movement") was appalled at that time to hear this, but it could explain her statement.

Okay, very speculative ... but [here](https://www.handelsblatt.com/arts_und_style/aus-aller-welt/mama-oder-mutti-ein-kosename-spaltet-die-republik/8190488.html) is an interesting article from which I quote

> **Ein Kosename spaltet die Republik**
> Westdeutschland sagt Mama, Ostdeutschland sagt Mutti: Eine aktuelle Umfrage hat gezeigt, dass die beliebteste Anrede für Mütter nicht einheitlich ist – und regional bedingt. Das zu erklären ist nicht leicht.
> [... ]
> Es gibt Belege dafür, dass "Mutti" im Nationalsozialismus ziemlich gebräuchlich war.

> **A term of endearment divides the republic**.
> West Germany says Mama, East Germany says Mutti: A recent survey has shown that the most popular form of address for mothers is not uniform - and regionally dependent. Explaining this is not easy.
> [... ]
> There is evidence that "Mutti" was quite common under National Socialism.

Comment: "Es gibt Belege dafür, dass "Mutti" im Nationalsozialismus ziemlich gebräuchlich war" is a pretty bs quotation (not your fault) not providing any evidence. *ngrams* shows "Mutti" is used a lot more in literature today than it was back then, so what? I also can't confirm that "west"="Mama" and "east"="Mutti" - That's more of a N/S divide.

Comment: @tofro Of course both variants "Mama / Mutti" and "Papa / Vati" have been popular for a long time. And certainly it is a primarily an individual  family thing which one is preferred. But I do not agree to your judgement that the linked article contains bs. It is based on empiric data though it is not clear how large the sample was (and thus the statistical significance is unclear). And ngram is not really conclusive because it only covers the written use and not oral use in families. Also see Carsten S's above comments.

Comment: @PaulFrost I removed the full quotation of the article. Quoting a full article is a violation of intellectual property rights, and could get us (the website) in trouble.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach I was not aware of this. Good to know it for future cases.

Comment: @PaulFrost  :+1 :)

Answer (score 0):

"Vati" and "Mutti" were still used in the 1950's.  When unions fought for Saturdays to be free, they came up with the slogan:  "Am Samstag gehoert Vati uns!," meaning "On Saturdays, Dad belongs to us!"  In those terribly conservative days, some married couples with children called each other also "Vati" and "Mutti", rather than by their actual first names.

Comment: Not directly an answer, but a datapoint that shows the east/west divide as claimed in other answers isn't quite true.