# Vati und Mutti? Still used?

Tags: word-usage, idiomaticity

I saw [this](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/38441/how-are-vati-and-mutti-used) discussion of Vati and Mutti. But I didn't see a resolution of whether they are still in use. One comment said they're used, others disagreed. One even said it's ironic negative to say Mutti. Any resolution?

Comment: Der Sprachgebrauch unterscheidet sich teils erheblich, abhängig von Alter, Religion und sozialer Klasse. Was in der einen Gruppe häufig ist, kann in einer anderen völlig out sein. Was für das eigene Milieu zutrifft, kann für ein anderes ganz falsch sein.

Comment: @userunknown: If the Question is written in English, please write your comments in English too. You you know if the questioner's German is good enough to understand your comment.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Wenn Du Deine Richtlinie ernst nimmst, hättest Du nicht auf meinen deutsch verfassten Kommentar deutsch antworten müssen? Nachtrag: Statt "Religion" wollte ich "Region" schreiben.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast - Getting off topic here, but I don't see a problem with commenting in German if you're not fluent in English. But schools in German speaking countries teach English from an early age so I'm not sure how often that situation would come up.

Comment: Faulheit treibt mich diesmal zum Englisch. Auf Deutsch zu antworten ist schwer in Ordnung.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was born 1965 in Graz (south-east of Autria). When I was a child, my parents taught me to call them »Mutti« and »Vati«, and I (now 57 years old, my parents are still alive) still use these names, and so does my sister too. Also all of my 13 cousins call their parents this way. (They in total have 12 parents, 10 of them are still alive.)

I also remember, that, when I was a child, my classmates used to call their parents this way too, and I guess, if they and their parents are still alive, most of them are still using these names for their parents.

But I don't hear »Vati« or »Mutti« out of the mouth of young adults, teenagers and children born after about 1980/1990. Most often I hear »Papa« and »Mama«. German speaking children don't use any other names. The next frequent names I hear here in eastern parts of Austria are »anne« (for the mother) and »baba« (for the father) in Vienna, but these are Turkish names used by Turkish speaking children.

Comment: I always considered Mama and Papa "English creep," i.e., encroaching English, and that Mutti and Vati were more original German. I just wanted to hear some opinions on the matter. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

They are still in use, but I do not know how many people actually use them to address father and mother. I think *Papa / Mama* and *Papi / Mami* are used much more frequently.

What is used may be a regional thing, but of above all it is an individual "family parlance". Using the official *Vater / Mutter* to address one's parents would be regarded as fairly reserved.

Be aware that all of these expressions are mainly used in spoken German. And if somebody speaks *about his parents* to people not belonging to the immediate family, he would most likely use the formal *Vater / Mutter* ("mein Vater ist 65 Jahre alt").

In written German (except in private letters or in novels reporting direct speech between family members) one would normally not use family parlance.

Is it ironic negative to say "Mutti"? The only context in which this is the case is when it is used as alias for the former chancellor Angela Merkel; at least this was the intention of many people using "Mutti Merkel". See [here](https://sz-magazin.sueddeutsche.de/frauen/die-mutti-aller-schlachten-83392) and [here](https://praxistipps.chip.de/warum-sagen-alle-mutti-zu-merkel-was-bedeutet-die-merkel-raute_91884).

Comment: Concerning the case of speaking *about* parents, there is an interesting case where you speak about parents of other little children, e.g. in child nursery or elementary school. As far as I can observe, the most common way to refer to them is actually "die Mama/der Papa von <Name des Kindes>". It seems to me that this happens (at least) for two reasons: 1) It matches the language commonly used by the children and is readily understood by both children and adults. 2) It refers to people who the children refer to as "Mama"/"Papa", ...

Comment: ... without implying that those people are also the (biological) mother/father of the children (which is not always the case).

Comment: About »regarded as fairly reserved«: Up to the middle of 20<sup>th</sup> century it was usual in many families that children addressed their parents with »Sie« (not with »du«). One of my uncles (the husband of one of my mothers sisters), who is about 80 years old now, used to use »Sie« for his parents during their whole life. This was even more common before about 1900.